Why does my HttpOnly Flag Cookie not get saved?
I have a .Net Core Backend running and its access point for request is http://localhost:5108/graphql/
If I execute a request from this endpoint I get back the cookie and my Browser saves it.

If I execute this from my fronted which runs on a different Port my cookie won't get saved. My Backend and my frontend uses currently http and not https

Here you can see that it does not get saved:

My cookie has the following parameters that are set in my backend:
httpOnly: true
path: "/"
samesite: "None"
secure: true

How can the frontend browser save the cookie now?

I blogged about how you can tell why cookies are blocked or not sent at https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/

I solved it.
I had to add withCredentials: true
export function apolloOptionsFactory(): ApolloClientOptions<any> {
  const httpLink = inject(HttpLink);
  return {
    // link: httpLink.create({ uri }),
    link: httpLink.create({ uri, withCredentials: true }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  };
}

